# Is it possible to use relative paths for directive templateUrls in AngularJS when bundling with Browserify?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browserify

I'm working on a web application using AngularJS, with Browserify to bundle my JS files into a single bundle for use in the page.  Currently my structure is something like this:

```
app
|-index.html
|-index.js
|-bundle.js
|-components
  |-module1
    |-index.js
    |-module1.directive.js
    |-module1.html
```

Because the bundled javascript file ends up in the app folder, my directives end up looking something like this:

```
module.exports = angular.module('module1.directive', [])
    .directive('moduleDirective', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: './components/module1/module1.html'
        );
    });
```

This works well enough in general, but the path could potentially get rather long if the project gets complex enough after more developers get involved and it's somewhat harder to move directives around when they're defined this way (changing the templateUrl path is an extra step that's relatively easy to forget).

What I'd like to know is, is there a way for me to use a relative path in the templateUrl so that Browserify will be able to resolve it correctly when bundling the files?

**EDIT:** If it helps, I could make this work if I could find a way to get the ORIGINAL file path for the script that's being bundled inside the module itself, but I don't know if Browserify supports that.

Answer (score 0):

Could the pathmodify plugin be a solution to your problem? More info can be found on github (https://github.com/jmm/pathmodify)

```
var pathmodify = require('pathmodify');
browserify()
     .plugin(pathmodify(), {mods: [
        // Make code like `require('app/something')` act like
        // `require('/somedir/src/something')`
        pathmodify.mod.dir('app', '/somedir/src')
]})
```

Comment: It looks handy, but as far as I can tell it's mainly meant for manually aliasing file paths (for example, mapping './components/module1' as 'module1' so that I can access that directory directly), which doesn't really help resolve the potential issues of more complex file structures and having to manage paths manually (I'd still have to alias each path manually, so I'd mostly just be moving the mess somewhere else).  I'll look at it a bit more and it might clean things up a bit, but as it stands I'm not sure it's going to help with my specific situation.